# C file extension if you include C file inside another

Tags: c, header-files

I have a C file with all static functions, related to one and same sub-task.

Some of the functions are quite long - 20-30 lines.

I want to include it in another C file.

What must be the file extension (in order things to considered professional). Shall I do it as H file?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Some people use `.inc`, some people use `.c`, some people use `.h`, and you don't even have to use extensions at all; because `#include` doesn't care.

Comment: never saw .inc in major C project?

Comment: It's definitely not uncommon.

Comment: Sometimes a `.def` suffix is used.

Comment: why not use head file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

20-30 lines isn't long. 200-300 lines is getting long but still doesn't warrant a separate file. 
Most projects would be unmanageable if 20 line functions had their own file.

Just put the functions in the `.c` file they're used in and declare them `static`.

I don't know what build tool you're using but traditional 'make' might get confused by `.c` unless you introduce further rules and discipline.

If you do put them in another file give it the `.inc` suffix as others suggest.

I have generally only seen people do this when the `.inc` is maintained by an external tool.

Comment: 200-300 lines is rather unprofessional I think. I did that years ago. Much better is small functions, compiler will inline most of them anyway. +1 for remembering that .c will confusing make.

Comment: @NIck I wouldn't use the word 'unprofessional' as that has connotations of dishonesty. But I agree. My answer shouldn't be taken as saying 200 lines is a good length for a function. But that even such biggies are rarely helped by farming them out to a included code file.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to share the same static methods across multiple c files (for compiler optimization?), you should place them in a `.c`-file and not in a `.h` file.

If you don't need to make those methods static, you should really place them in a single `.c` module which is liked to the binary and only share the definitions across the modules using them.

Example

## If you really have to share the static functions and you have a *really* good reason

#### static_functions.c (I'd name it static_functions.inc.c, but that's personal flavour)

```
static int max(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b)
        return a;
    return b;
}
```

#### module-x.c for some x

```
#include "static_functions.c"
int use_max() {
    return max(1,2);
}
```

Compile `module-x.c` only.

### If you don't really need static versions

#### internal_functions.h

```
#ifndef internal_functions_h
#define internal_functions_h
int max(int a, int b);
#endif
```

#### internal_functions.c

```
#include "internal_functions.h"
int max(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b)
        return a;
    return b;
}
```

#### module-x.c for some x

```
#include "internal_functions.h"
int use_max() {
    return max(1,2);
}
```

And then compile and link together `internal_functions.c` and `module-x.c`.
To have the definitions local only, you don't need to use or ship your `internal_functions.h` elsewhere.

Comment: #include "static_functions.c" - I am doing exactly this. but don't .C means something that needs to be compiled alone?   (also sorry for using word "methods", is pure C)

Comment: You can name your files as you like it. You can even call it `.jpg` if you call your compiler correctly. Usually header files `.h` *should* not contain implementations, `.c`-files *might* contain implementations.

Comment: ...and .h files may contain small inline static functions

Answer (score 2):

> include C file inside another

No, not the way. Conventionally,

- `.c` *[source files]* are meant to be compiled and linked together
- `.h` *[Header files]* are there to be `include`d.

> C file with all static methods [] Shall I do it as H file?

No. *Ideally* header files [`.h`] are not supposed to contain any definition. There should be declarations only. Otherwise, if a header file `.h` contains definitions and you've got `include`d them more than once, you'll be facing multiple definition issue.

I have a little doubt regarding

> C file with ***all*** static methods.

If **all** the methods [functions] are `static`, how to use them, anyway?

However, the way for you will be taking all the related `.c` files, compile and link them together to form the final binary.

Comment: sorry for using word methods instead of function, i am thinking OO way.

Comment: the static functions are used only in single c file, I don't want to be exposed in .o file. If I ever need them in two files, I will do #ifndef as in H file, but will keep them static.

Answer (score 1):

Do not include separate c files. Just compile them separately as they are.

Suppose you have two files with code: main.c and include.c.

Rather than having `#include "include.c"` inside main.c, when you compile link the object files:

```
gcc main.c include.c
```

Comment: If I do so, there must be at least one non static function.